# Call a Selected Index for next view controller

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to get a specific segue to trigger when I click the specific image that is being displayed by the carousel at the time.

I am getting the error:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'SelectedIndex'

The end goal is to trigger a segue for each of the images in my array.

here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class PacksPage: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var iCarouselView: iCarousel!

    var imageArray = [  UIImage(named:"PeoplePack") ,
                        UIImage(named:"MachineryPack") ,
                        UIImage(named:"ArchitecturePack") ,
                        UIImage(named:"MoneyPack") ,
                        UIImage(named:"AnimalPack") ,
                        UIImage(named:"PrimitivePack") ,
                        UIImage(named:"GalacticPack") ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        iCarouselView.type = .invertedCylinder
        iCarouselView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    }
}

extension PacksPage: iCarouselDelegate, iCarouselDataSource{
    func numberOfItems(in carousel: iCarousel) -> Int {
        return imageArray.count
    }

    func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, viewForItemAt index: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
        var imageView: UIImageView!
        if view == nil {
            imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 530))
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        } else {
            imageView = view as? UIImageView
        }

        imageView.image = imageArray[index]
        return imageView
    }

    func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, didSelectItemAt index: Int)
    {
        SelectedIndex = index
        self .performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowAnimalPack", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is correct, there is no `SelectedIndex` variable in the code you posted.

Comment: @rmaddy I get that the error is correct, but how do i state that when a certain part of my array is showing it performs the segue?

Answer (score 0):

The error "Use of unresolved identifier 'SelectedIndex'" means that you are trying to call something that has not been defined in the current scope.

Here, you do not have anything described in the name of 'SelectedIndex'.

From your code, I understand that you are trying to call a selected index for your next View Controller.
If this is the case, and I hope you have a var named selectedIndex of type Int in your destination view controller.

//Edited as per your comment

Have a variable described in your PacksPage class to hold the value of the selected Index, like:

```
var index: Int?
```

In your selected index method,

```
func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, didSelectItemAt index: Int)
{
    self.index = index
    self .performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowAnimalPack", sender: nil)
}
```

This would store the index value of the cell on to self.index. Then you may prepare segue and pass the same value to the next view controller like below.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ShowAnimalPack"{
        if let  destinationController = segue.destination as? DestinationControllerClass{
        destinationController.selectedIndex = index // where index is a variable in your PacksPage class to which you may assign a value when the carousel item is clicked.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the code for the variable I’m supposed to put on my destination view controller? Also, I think you meant destination.selectedIndex.

Comment: edited the answer. Then again, did you search for the error message in stack overflow? This could be marked as a duplicate question.

Comment: Instead of instantiating a new view controller called `DestinationControllerClass`, the segue already knows its destination, which is available as `segue.destination` that can be typecast using `as? DestinationViewController`. If this fails then something went wrong and the segue identifier does not match the intended destination.

Comment: Also, instead of storing the index as a variable and increasing it's scope so that it can be changed from multiple sources, the segue's `sender` was built for passing this type of information. So instead of passing a `nil` sender you can pass the `index` and then unwrap it in the `prepareForSegue` method

Comment: My bad. I didn't check the answer in Xcode before submitting it. It seems segue.destination is a get only property. Edited the answer as needed.

Comment: Well, I believe that the OP is new to Swift programming and iOS application development in general. So, I kept the solution as simple as possible for the OP.
In my case, I wouldn't have even used the Segue in the first place. But still, this gets the job done for the OP.

Comment: What is my selected index method? and how do I do this for every image in my array? Sorry if I'm being a burden, you're right I am new to Xcode but I am 17 and an experienced graphic designer with an ambitious app idea, the app is beautiful but the code isn't.

Comment: func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, didSelectItemAt index: Int)
 This method will get called every time you click on an item. What you need to do is et the index of the cell that you selected store it in a variable in your controller and call a segue.
In the prepare for segue override, you pass this index value to the next view controller.